# How to validate alphabets in android?

Tags: android

How to **validate edittext field so that it should not accept alphabets when entered and it should accept only numbers**? I have written the code for empty edittext...i.e if nothing is entered in the editetext **an alert will be raised**. But how to make my edittext to accept only numbers and not alphabets?
    Help me regarding this....Will be thankful to you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

set the InputType as number to your EditField to accept only number

For Example

```
<EditText

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You Simply need to use Input Type as Numeric in your xml file just like below

```
android:inputType="number"
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can use regularexpressions

```
   if (!Pattern.matches("^[0-9 ]*$", s))

    {                   
       et.setError("Allow only Numerics");

     }
```

or
     u  specify

```
        android:inputType="number"
```

for your edittext in ur xml file

Answer (score 0):

use this in your edittext :

```
android:hint="@string/phone_no_hint"
android:digits="0123456789"
android:inputType="phone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:inputType="number"` in the declaration of the `EditText`. This will simply disallow entry of anything other than numbers by displaying a numeric keypad.